# BroadCastReceiver não é chamadado em alguns dispositivos

Tags: android

Estou criando alarmes com AlarmManager, em alguns dispositivos o alarme funciona, mas em outros como ASUS e XIAOMI não funciona, nem mesmo enta na classe receiver, alguém já passou por isso?

**Metódo que cria o alarme**

```java
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), TesteAlarmeReceiver.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = 
    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 1232312, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "call alarmManager.set()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**Manifest**

```xml
<receiver android:name=".teste_alarme.TesteAlarmeReceiver"
            android:process=":remote" />
```

**Receiver**

```java
public class TesteAlarmeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("Paulo","Receiver");
        Toast.makeText(context,
                "AlarmReceiver.onReceive()",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Jovem, encontrei essa questão na stack em inglês: [questão.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35718468/boot-broadcastreceiver-does-not-work-on-xiaomi-devices)

Comment: Sou autor dela também.